# Meteor OAuth Server error: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Instagram

Tags: meteor, oauth, instagram

I'm using https://github.com/meteor-helium/instagram package to handle Instagram login.

In my server/social-config.js, I have

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
    service: 'instagram'
});
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: 'instagram',
    clientId: '****',
    secret: '****'
});
```

In my client/main.html, I have

```
<template name="login">
{{#if currentUser}}
    <button id="logout">Logout</button>
{{else}}
    <button id="instagram-login" class="btn btn-default"> Login with Instagram</button>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

In my client/main.js, I have

```
Template.login.events({
'click #instagram-login': function(event) {
    Meteor.loginWithInstagram({}, function(err){
        if (err) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("Instagram login failed");
        }
    });
},

'click #logout': function(event) {
    Meteor.logout(function(err){
        if (err) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("Logout failed");
        }
    })
}
});
```

I get the following error when I click the "Sign in with Instagram" button

```
Error in OAuth Server: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Instagram. failed [400] {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Invalid Client Secret"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that according to this https://github.com/meteor-helium/instagram/blob/master/instagram_configure.js#L10
The client secret property name should be `clientSecret`, not `secret`.

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: 'instagram',
    clientId: '****',
    clientSecret: '****'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but with **Google**:

```
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966810914Z Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Google. failed [401] {   "error": "unauthorized_client",   "error_description": "Unauthorized" }
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966854103Z     at getTokens (packages/google-oauth/google_server.js:105:7)
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966858709Z     at MethodInvocation.<anonymous> (packages/google-oauth/google_server.js:63:27)
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966863213Z     at packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:512:31
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966880535Z     at tryLoginMethod (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1305:14)
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966885506Z     at AccountsServer._runLoginHandlers (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:510:22)
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966889786Z     at MethodInvocation.methods.login (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:570:31)
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966893775Z     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1803:12)
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966897605Z     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:727:19
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966901725Z     at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1234:12)
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966905836Z     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:725:46
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966909853Z     at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1234:12)
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966913596Z     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:723:46
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966917555Z     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966922191Z     at Session.method (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:697:23)
app                | 2021-09-02T22:36:53.966927541Z     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:561:43
```

The client is a react native app, so, to solve it, make sure to use **the same clientId** in the server and in the mobile app.

Below is a picture where you can see different Client IDs, you need to choose **Web Client** option:

*GCP platform -> API & Services -> Credentials*

[image]

Also, make sure to add known domains for that client id record.

[image]

This allows to use OAuth Google either in localhost or in a server with domain.